# How can I upload mutlple images at same time in Django?

Tags: django, image, django-models, django-forms

I need upload multiple images in my form but I have just one imagefield, i don't want to have more imagefields the main idea is do a for each in the save method or something like that, but I don't have any idea to do that, please help.

This is my model:

```
class Archivos(models.Model):
    id_archivo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_unidad = models.IntegerField()
    nombre_archivo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    imagen  = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', null=True, blank=True)
```

I EDITED my def post

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('imagen')
    if form.is_valid():
        a = 0
        for imagen in files:
            a = a+1
            img = form.save(commit=False)
            img.id_unidad = 1
            img.nombre_archivo ='hhh'+ str(a) 

            img.save()
        print(a);

        return self.form_valid(form)

    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The for cicle works but always save the last image. I think it is working like and update but I don't understand why?

this is part of  my form in a template:

[the multiple imagefield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVs1e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Zagorodniy suggested you probably want an extra table to keep the collection of uploaded images related to each other, using a `ForeignKey` in your image table. (if you need such a thing).

Anyway, to save multiple images, create instances of `Archivos` model in for loop and save it one by one:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('imagen')
if form.is_valid():

    for image in files:
        instance = Planfile(
        nombre_archivo = ... ,
        id_unidad = ... ,
        imagen = image  
        )
        instance.save()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the choices is to create one more model for example `ArchivosGallery` with `ForeignKey` on your product. For example, if your product model called `Archivos`, then you should create:

```
class ArchivosGallery(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(u'Images', upload_to='countries/images/', blank=True)
  countries = models.ForeignKey('Archivos', blank=True, null=True)
```

to add images in product admin you have to add this code in `admin.py`:

```
class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = ArchivosGallery

class ArchivosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [
    ImagesInline,
  ]
admin.site.register(Archivos, ArchivosAdmin)
```

Hope its helps you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access multipart values with getlist:

Here's an example:

```
for bfile in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
    File(file=bfile, files=testing).save()
```